# SSH Remote File Execution

Tags: bamboo

I am trying to start a Powershell script in remote windows 2012 server with Bitvise. The script has the command to start a spring boot application.

```
start "MyApp" java -jar myapp.jar
```

Bamboo Job triggers the script using SSH task and based on the logs, the jar is executed and the application is up. However, as soon as the bamboo job completes, the application goes down. Is there a way to keep this application running even after the job completes?

**Note**: I tried running a bat file instead of PowerShell and in that case the bamboo job simply never completes and if the job is manually stopped the application goes down in the server.

Regards,

Jai

Comment: The program is started by the user when they login and stopped when they logout. You would need to detach the spawned process from the user. Maybe this will help: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-11488?

Comment: Thanks for response @Hive7 U are correct about the behaviour. I am trying to run it as a detached process. Since I have a windows server nhop won't work for me. My options are running as a service or scheduled tasks. But both require admin privileges. I am not sure if it is recommended to ssh and run a script as an admin user on the server. The script will start a spring boot application and appln is safe and all but I am not sure if what I am doing is correct. Any advice?